# CodeIgniter Controllers functions is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have deployed my site on a VPN server. I am able to access the controller constructor, but when I am trying to call any method like `mydomain/controller/method`, it is not working. However 'mydomain/controller/index' is also not working.

When I am debugging with php method `function_exists('my function name')` then also it is coming up false even though that method exist in my controller.

Please help with this problem, and let me know if I have to do any config changes.

Thanks!

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get any PHP errors? Any output in any way? Any HTTP status codes? Just give us something to work on....

Comment: No i have no seen error only blank page.

Comment: That probably means that your PHP fails silently because you haven't enabled error reporting. Take a look in your error log on your server, it will probably contain some PHP errors. Or [enable error reporting](http://www.google.dk/#q=enable+php+error+reporting)

Comment: Are you using htaccess to rewrite your URLs?

Comment: How can i check error in file with php functions is there any?

Comment: No i am not using the htaccess but it is reside in application dir.

Comment: can anyone help me i found this error in error_log file "an unknown filter was not added: PHP"

Comment: @Arshad, what happens when you go to http://mydomain/index.php/controller/method ??

Comment: The blank page.and found above error in error_log file.No function is working in controller..:( pls help

Comment: yes i have create a test.php with class in root of CodeIgniter dir.It is working fine.but not the controller....:(

Comment: The problem is with your webserver, not with your code. The error_log file tells you that it doesn't know what the PHP filter is. In other words, your server configuration is wrong.

Comment: what i have to made change in httpd.conf file to run file successfully.please suggust...

Comment: `function_exists()` doesn't work on methods.

Comment: You may have written same function twice? Or called model function which doesn't exist? Have you extended controller class with following:           class class_name extends CI_Controller

Comment: Google it; we don't know anything about your setup at all; we would have to guess on almost anything about your server.

Comment: yes i have extended however it is calling constructor but not any function....:(

Answer (score 7):

You will need to navigate to `http://mydomain/index.php/controller/method`

... unless you specifically have a `.htaccess` file in the root where `index.php` is that eliminates `index.php` from the URL.

If you have this .htaccess file set correctly you will be able to navigate to `http://mydomain/controller/method`

here is an example of an .htaccess file for codeigniter that I'm using for debugging.

```
php_flag display_errors on 
php_value error_reporting 7 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

copy all of this text to a file called .htaccess and put it where index.php is in the codeigniter root directory.

///////////////// *Edit based on more info from OP* //////////////////

First test to see if the following works..

Unless you deleted it, CI provides you, by default a welcome controller `(/application/controllers/welcome.php)` and a welcome view thats being called by the controller `(/application/views/welcome_message.php)`.

See if these files are there and if they aren't get them from the zip file in the codeigniter framework and put it in these directories.

navigate to the config folder and open `routes.php` `(/application/config/routes.php)` and under `reserved routes` put in `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";` if it's not already there.

In addition make sure you have the Config changed to reflect the fact that you are using the .htaccess file.

the property should be set as follows in config.php `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Note that if you are not using .htaccess this would be set to `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

These instructions are in an effort to get you to see something on the page. You would change the default controller to your controller (not welcome) when you get going with the above.

Comment: Are you even able to load the sample page without any modifications? Also, look into getting the Firebug/FirePHP combo for firefox.

Comment: yes i have create a test.php with class in root of CodeIgniter dir.It is working fine.but not the controller....:(

Comment: OK, ok we're getting closer to the problem. You said you created a test.php in the CI root? What for?? You wouldn't normally use this file in a CI build being in the CI root. Anyways, that's not what i was getting at. In a CI build you get a welcome controller with a view are you seeing this welcome message?

Comment: Did you try everything I suggested? If yeah, there is something more esoteric going on that we'll need more information on to help. The only other thing I can suggest at this point is to download the whole framework again, put it into a new location on the server. Navigate to the location + /index.php/welcome.php and see if that works. If it doesn't there could be something wrong with the server/ports etc.