# Codeigniter HMVC new controller function not working while old one is working

Tags: codeigniter

I've built a project on CodeIgniter. I've one main domain for instance "example.com" and one subdomain for instance "control.example.com". The directory structure is:

```
public_html
     -- application
     -- system
     -- index.php
     -- .htaccess
     -- CodeIgniter_framework related files and folder
     -- control (** for subdomain control.example.com and Codeigniter HMVC framework)
     ------ application
        -------- config
        -------- other files and folders
        -------- modules
          ----------- user
            ----------- controllers
              ------------- User.php
            ----------- models
              ------------- User_model.php
            ----------- view
              ------------- index.php
              ------------- other views
     ------ system
     ------ index.php
     ------ .htaccess
```

The User.php controller has many methods like index, search, and other functions.
Everything is working fine, I've uploaded the project to the server and it's working as designed & developed.

The problem arises when I declare a new route and new controller function for this route in User.php Controller. It is showing 404 error. I browse the internet for solutions and find lots of questions regarding this but nothing is working.

The main problem is that it is not accepting the new controller functions while old function is acceptable when I used them for the route. for instanc:

```
$route['user_search'] = "user/index"; // working "index" method is old
$route['user_search'] = "user/search"; // working "search" method is old
$route['user_search'] = "user/user_search"; // not working "user_search" method is new
$route['user_search'] = "user/test_search"; // not working "test_search" method is new
```

I've tried a lots of solution like
[CodeIgniter: 404 Page Not Found on Live Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709185/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-on-live-server) or [CodeIgniter Controllers functions is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531495/codeigniter-controllers-functions-is-not-working) etc.

I've checked on Naming conventions for controller, models, view, for CI HMVC, try different .htacces codes, permissions for folders and files, all are correct. But still facing the same issue.

The problem is with the new declared function/method on the User.php controller, the same is working for the old one.

Error log is just

```
ERROR - 2022-03-26 11:13:46 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
```

Comment: Did you give the new routes a unique key in the `$route` array? In your example you're using the same key `$route['user_search']` for all of them, which may also cause problems.

Comment: @Marleen The above listed route is single. It is just for defining the problem that same route is working when old method index, search were used but not when new method user_search or test_search were used for route

Comment: are you keeping old routes with new one or replacing they with new one.

Comment: @umefarooq Keeping old routes and creating new routes for new pages with new controller function and view. Not to mention that new routes are unique with unique controller function and view. When new routes defined with old controller function works but with new controller function not working.